# set the value for a checkbox using .prop

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So, I have in my script the following code to assign the value of several text boxes that is working ok.

However, when I attempt to assign the value of a checkbox, nothing seems to be set for the checkbox. I have tried using .prop and .attr, so I am thinking my entire approach is wrong.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my unchanged code. I am trying to assign the value of the "#id_language_detail_multiple_languages":

```
    function setLanguageDetailsFormValues() {

    $('#id_language_detail_display_type').val('{{ language_details.language_detail_display_type }}');

    $('#id_language_detail_multiple_languages').val('{{ language_details.language_detail_multiple_languages }}');

    ....
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML markup?

Comment: How are you checking if the value has been set?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the "value" of your text boxe, you will add to do something like this:

```
$('#YourId').attr('value', 'setYourValueHere')
```

If you want to have the value of your text box, just do:

```
var myValue = $('#YourId').attr('value')
```

That is the same thing for '.prop' !

If it wasn't what you wanted, be a little more specific or give us a http://jsfiddle.net/ :-)

By the way, you can also do:

if you go 1 checkbox:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val('yourValue');
```

Or just:

```
document.getElementById('yourCheckbox').value = 'YourValue';
```

If the value isn't set, it will return undefined, so be aware and check if it is !

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can do it like following.Properties for checkboxes are different from textboxes.

`$("#CheckboxID").prop("checked","True");`

if you want to read the checkbox value use like following

```
$("#CheckboxID").prop("checked");
```

Thanks.